# Numerically solve integral with a function as variable of integration

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, matlab, computational-mathematics

I want to use a function as variable of integration for example in evaluating the integral:

$\int_0^1 e^{\cos x}f(\sin x)d\cos x$

in which $f(x)$ is an arbitrary function.

Comment: Just rewrite as $$\int e^x f(\sqrt{1-x^2})dx$$

Comment: That will work for the case I specified, great! But is there also a general method for a case in which this doesn't work?

Comment: Well when I integrate with respect to a function, it is no different then saying y is that function and I am integrating wrt y. Note if $y=\cos x$ then $d\cos x=dy$, $e^{\cos x}=y$ and $\sin x = \sqrt{1-\cos^2 x}=\sqrt{1-y^2}$. Of course in this case I swapped y with x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To formalise the comments, you can take $y=\cos x$ so $d\cos x=dy$ and $\sin x = \sqrt{1-\cos^2x}=\sqrt{1-y^2}$ therefore your integral is $$\int_0^1 e^yf\left(\sqrt{1-y^2}\right)dy$$